# Social share from webpage

Tags: javascript, youtube, vimeo

I am developing a website with share buttons for social medias like Facebook and Twitter. Like: [Sharingbuttons.io](https://sharingbuttons.io/)

I was wondering if there is a way to implement the same share feature to Tik Tok, Youtube, and Vimeo. I researched and haven't found a way so far.

Comment: What do yo mean by the same share feature

Comment: @Andam share content to these three social medias from a button in my web site

Answer (score 5):

Not really, the thing is that Youtube, Vimeo, and Tik Tok do not really have a share like facebook and twitter do. Yes you can send messages to your friends, or post it on your youtube 'feed', but it doesn't quite work the same as facebook or twitter sharing.

Furthermore, if the capability existed, the website of the company would have all the information about creating embeded share buttons such as facebook an twitter do. Similar with their API information.

I know it's probably not the answer you wanted, and I might not be 100% correct, but after looking around for a bit and testing some of my own code, I did not manage to find an effective solution.

**DISCLAIMER:**
I am not responsible for anything you do, this is just for information purposes only.

A complicated workaround might be to save the webpage you want the user to be at when they click the button, in this case your Tik Tok share page, and then feed their comment into the empty textboxes using javascript, but then when they are redirected to this site, they would be asked to signin, and their information would be needed. Then all the stuff they wrote when they were planning on sharing would disappear and they would be logged into the Tik Tok page.

Also this is probably illegal begause it involves you serving them a page that is "Tik Tok", but in reality it's just your webpage so you can pass information along to the real website.

Cheers!